# Group UNION-ised Results while not losing columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, union

I am having the following problem:

I have the following result set:

```
| ForecastAmount | AmountAchieved | MonthID | EmployeeID | ForecastWeek | WeekAchieved |
|       NULL     |     51.541     |   132   |      7     |      NULL    |    2014-09   |
|       NULL     |    101.223     |   132   |     31     |      NULL    |    2014-09   |
|     220.000    |      NULL      |   132   |      7     |    2014-05   |      NULL    |
|     214.5665   |      NULL      |   132   |     31     |    2014-05   |      NULL    |
```

Which I get by doing something analogically to the following query:

```
       SELECT SUM(Amount) as ForecastAmount
             ,NULL as AmountAchieved
             ,MonthID
             ,ForecastWeek
             ,NULL as WeekAchieved
             ,EmployeeID
       FROM (Query 1)
   UNION
      SELECT NULL as ForecastAmount
            ,Sum(AmountAchieved)
            ,MonthID
            ,NULL as ForecastWeek
            ,WeekAchieved
            ,EmployeeID
      FROM (Query 2)
Group by MonthID,ForecastWeek,WeekAchieved,EmployeeID
```

Now what I want is the following:

```
| ForecastAmount | AmountAchieved | MonthID | EmployeeID | ForecastWeek | WeekAchieved |
|     220.000    |     51.541     |   132   |      7     |    2014-05   |    2014-09   |
|     214.5665   |    101.223     |   132   |     31     |    2014-05   |    2014-09   |
```

So basically what I want is the same result set grouped by *EmployeeID* and *Month*, while **ForecastWeek** and **WeekAchieved** are not left out, but rather fall into the right places.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you do something as simple as taking the MAX ForecastWeek and WeekAchieved rather than including it in the GROUP BY?

Comment: discover [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms181765.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to do a simple aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) as ForecastAmount,
       SUM(AmountAchieved) as AmountAchieved,
       MonthID,
       MAX(ForecastWeek) as ForecastWeek,
       MAX(WeekAchieved) as WeekAchieved,
       EmployeeID
FROM (Query 1) q
GROUP BY MonthID, EmployeeID;
```

Comment: I Need Query 2, because i don't have the Values i assign  NULL to in Query 1 in Query 1

Comment: Are you sure you need Query 2 as a separate query, and not just a JOIN? Can you include the entire query?

Comment: Yes, i have found it, the solution would be a FULL JOIN